# Чи оглушується звук [г] у словах: Бангкок, пругкий, оргкомітет, мигкотіти, перемогти?

Tags: фонетика

У правилах до вимови приголосних звуків сказано, що дзвінкі приголосні [б], [д], [з], [д͡з], ['ж], [д͡ж], [г], [ґ] у кінці слова і в кінці складу перед глухим приголосним вимовляються дзвінко.

Але в той же момент подані такі винятки, як [лехкий], [вохкий], [к'іхт'і], [н'іхт'і], [д'охт'у].

Натомість про слова **Бангкок**, **пругкий**, **оргкомітет**, **мигкотіти**, **перемогти** нічого не сказано. Чи в них звук [г] також оглушується? Якщо ні, то чому? Чому лише подані слова є винятками?

Comment: Ви вимовляєте ці слова з написаними буквами?

Comment: Цікаво, не впевнений на 100%, чи це академічно вірно, але як носій мови я оглушую [г] у даних випадках.

Answer (score 2):

[Орфоепічний словник / уклад. М. І. Погрібний. – Київ: Рад. шк., 1984. – 629 c. — с. 11](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/E_LIB/PDF/ukr0001233.pdf#page=11):

> [image: Фрагмент із книги]

[А. Й. Вагмут. Оглушення приголосних звуків // Українська мова: енциклопедія / НАН України, Інститут мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні, Інститут української мови; ред. В. М. Русанівський [та ін.]. — К.: Українська енциклопедія, 2000. — ISBN 966-7492-07-9. — с. 424–425](https://archive.org/stream/UkrMovEnts#page/n423/mode/2up):

> **ОГЛУ́ШЕННЯ ПРИ́ГОЛОСНИХ** — фонет. явище, коли дзвінкий приголосний вимовляється
> як глухий, тобто відбувається нейтралізація глухих і дзвінких приголосних (пор. *Одзвінчення приголосних*). Староукр. пам’ятки відбивають це явище, починаючи з 14 ст. (росказати, росправи, прутко, світки). Втрата дзвінкості як однієї з диференц. ознак укр. фонет. системи є наслідком накладання *артикуляції* у групах приголосних. О. п. — це втрата голосності у гомоорганних приголосних, які утворюють пари за ознакою дзвінкості/глухості: **д—т**, **з—с**, **б—п**, **ж—ш**,
> **г—х(к)**, **д͡з—ц**, **д͡ж—ч**. При О. п. розрізняють два види змін: а) модифікацію (видозміну) звуків у *мовному потоці* й б) чергування *фонем*. Модифікація пов’язана з частковими змінами фонем, коли звук не змінює своєї залежності до певної фонеми, але набуває ін. відтінку (чергування *алофонів*). О. п. при цьому може мати як комбінаторний (**перемогти[хт]**, **підшити[тш]**),
> так і позиц. характер (**без тебе[ст]**, **під коморою [тк]**). Якщо О. п. відбувається внаслідок впливу на дзвінкий приголосний наст. глухого — це називається регресивною *асиміляцією*. Варіативною формою є вимова з неповним
> оглушенням звука [**г**] у кінці слова або в позиції між голосними: борг [**борг̭**], чого [**чог̭о**]. Чергування звуків відбувається внаслідок асиміляції приголосних за місцем і способом творення: **принісши [шш]**, **зжитися [жж]**, **безшумно [шш]**. О. п. закономірне в усній мові. Укр. орфографія фіксує його в написанні ряду слів (**ліщина**, **піщаний**, **дощаний**, **натхненний**) та префікса **з-** (**спалахнути**, **схил**). О. п. є нормативним у словах **ні́гті**, **кі́гті**, **ле́гко**, **во́гко**, **дігтя́р** і в їхніх похідних, а також у префіксі (й прийменнику) **з** перед глухими приголосними: **зсув** [с:у́ў],
> **зчеп** [шчеп]. Паралельні форми (тобто з О. п. і без нього) є нормативними для префіксів **роз-** і **без-**: **розквіт** [ро́зквʼіт], [ро́сквʼіт]. Не характерне оглушення для звукосполучень з трьох і чотирьох приголосних (**відстрілювати**, **розстріл**, **підставка**). Воно може залежати від темпу і стилю вимови. Для укр. літ. вимови не є властивим О. п. у кінці слова (**дуб**, **листопад**). У говорах укр. мови *південно-західного наріччя* зазнають асиміляції у позиції перед глухими кореневі дзвінкі приголосні (**блиско** — літ. **близько**, **нішка** — літ. **ніжка**).

Висновки, що я можу зробити:

- коли [Яна Сергієнко каже в своїй відповіді](/a/6453), що зазвичай **оглушуються лише похідні від *легко*, *вогко*, *нігті*, *кігті*, *дьоготь* [і також певною мірою префікси та прийменники]**, то вона рацію — багато джерел стверджують саме так (на додачу до зазначених вище: [розділ «Норми української орфоепії»](https://fil.wikireading.ru/53464) у посібнику В. В. Молдована «Судова риторика», [стаття на dyskurs.net](https://dyskurs.net/upodibnennia-dzvinkykh-i-hlukhykh-pryholosnykh-teoriia-typovi-testy-zno/));
- але якщо пірнути дещо глибше, зокрема окрім повного оглушування розглядати знеголошування / неповне оглушування і/або діалекти, то картина дещо ускладнюється/розмивається.

Answer (score -1):

Цей список винятків - повний. Тобто, дійсно тільки в тих словах відбувається оглушення звука г. Відповідно на слова, про які ви питаєте (Бангкок", "пругкий", "оргкомітет", "мигкотіти", "перемогти"), поширюється правило збереження дзвінкості перед глухими.

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди наводьте джерела.

Comment: Приклади джерел, що, здається, підтверджують Вашу думку: http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/E_LIB/PDF/ukr0001233.pdf#page=11, https://dyskurs.net/upodibnennia-dzvinkykh-i-hlukhykh-pryholosnykh-teoriia-typovi-testy-zno/, https://fil.wikireading.ru/53464